# How to handle redirect 302 in extjs form submit

Tags: redirect, extjs

Before form is submit it go through session checking and if session was timeout it will redirect to login page. This is where the problem occur because it is ajax form submit so failure: handle this, but what extjs return to separate redirect from other kind of error ?

Answer (score 1):

If your session is timed out, do you need the server to return a json and handle it in the failure or success handler of the ajax request?

But if your session has expired, you need to redirect the user to your login page. In that case, you need not worry about what the json response would be and how ExtJS will handle it.

For a 302 error, its the web server that provides the alternate URL and not the browser. The 302 response from the Web server should always include an alternative URL to which redirection should occur. So, in your case you should redirect the user to the login page of your application.

Comment: The problem is if I open the form submit page and the session expired user can still post the form, but nothing will occur.
It will fall to failure: section, but won't redirect to anywhere.

Comment: when user post the form, check if the session is active. If its not active, redirect the page.

Comment: You mean check before send post request ?

Comment: how are you checking if a session is valid or not? on the server side code right? When the data is posted, first check if the session is valid, if its not valid, redirect to your login page. Else process the form data.

Comment: I didn't write the code response for session checking myself, but it define in web.xml <filter> and for normal get request it work fine redirecting user to login page, but when it come to form submit from extjs (which is ajax I think) it not working and redirect to no where.